# SQL Server function and transaction

Tags: sql-server

I am new in it field went through some answers but not getting any simple answer of this to understand...

Why are transaction not recommended in SQL Server functions?

Comment: Transactions are not allowed in user-defined functions. Use a stored-procedure then

Comment: You can't use even DML in UDF to wrap it with transaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use user defined function to modify database state. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

That’s why transactions are unnecessary for sql-server functions.

However, you can change transaction isolation level, for example, you may use NOLOCK hint to reach "read uncommitted" transaction isolation level and read uncommitted data from other transactions.